# Change of variables in multiple integral

Tags: integration

Suppose we are given an integral $\int_{E} f(\mathbf{x}) \, d \mathbf{x}$, where $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ and where $\mathbf{x} = c \mathbf{y}$, where $c$ is any constant. How do we make a change of variables to this, writing the integral in the form $\int_{S} g(\mathbf{y}) \, d \mathbf{y}$? How do we make a change of variables in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the Jacobian. If you want to make the change of variables $\mathbf{x} = g(\mathbf{y})$, where $g$ is injective on $E$, and $g(F) = E$ then the Jacobian is defined by $J_g(\mathbf{y}) = \det \big(g^\prime(\mathbf{y})\big)$, where $g^\prime(\mathbf{y})$ is the derivative matrix of $g$ evaluated at $\mathbf{y}$. Then the change of variables is given by
$$
\int_E f(\mathbf{x}) d\mathbf{x} = \int_F f(g(\mathbf{y})) |J_g(\mathbf{y})| d\mathbf{y}.
$$
In your case, the Jacobian of $\mathbf{x} = g(\mathbf{y}) = c\mathbf{y}$ is just $c^n$ since $g^\prime(\mathbf{y}) = c I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix, and $F = \frac{1}{c} E = \{ \mathbf{x}/c : \mathbf{x} \in E\}$. Therefore,
$$
\int_E f(\mathbf{x}) d\mathbf{x} = \int_F f(c \mathbf{y}) |c^n| d\mathbf{y}.
$$
Check out [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Substitution_for_multiple_variables) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The Jacobian of the transformation is $cI$, with determinant $c^n$.